# update values in firebase using a from with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an attendance system using firebase and I'm facing a problem creating a from to show the attended students and to attend them using that form.

[image: Here is my firebase structure]

aiming to display it like this:

```
Student ID: 43101476
16-10-2018 [✓]
17-10-2018 [  ]
19-10-2018 [✓]
20-10-2018 [ ]
[Submit]
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I only have the firebase paths to reach the data, I just don't know how to put it in a form of checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read all dates from the node you show in your screenshots, and generate an HTML checkbox and label for each:

```
var ref = firebase.datatabase.ref("252343/435101476");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    var date = child.key;
    var value = child.val();
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = date;
    checkbox.name = date;
    checkbox.value = value;

    var label = document.createElement('label')
    label.htmlFor = date;
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date));

    document.body.appendChild(label);
    document.body.appendChild(checkbox);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just added the Jquery `$(":checkbox[value=true]").attr("checked","true");` to make the attended students checked, but now is there a way to update the values in the firebase based on the values i enter using the form